# how to forward port 80 traffic via PHP to another website and return response

Tags: php, portforwarding

I would like to forward all incoming input from "client0" on my website [www.example.com/test.php](http://www.example.com/test.php) to my other website [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com) and return the answer back the same way.
So when I open [www.example.com/test.php](http://www.example.com/test.php) it should be like I am on [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com). Is that possible for js,html,css content?

Any hint would be appreciated =)

thank you!

Comment: It's far easier if you set up a reverse proxy on your webserver instead unless you also want to run extra PHP code

Comment: Agreed, you wouldn't do that via PHP code, it's a server config thing - proxying or redirects are likely to be your friends.

Comment: Sure if I could. The webhosting was a special offer so I lack permissions to do so.  Redirecting is not what I am looking for =)

Comment: Or use iframe with example1.com in it

Comment: I wrote a small PHP proxy once and it isn't difficult, just very tedious and probably unreliable. You can get request data with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` (verb), `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (parameters) and `php://input` (request payload) and then send HTTP requests with the tool of your choice (streams or Curl extension). As said, web servers are already very good at that. Do you need to process or alter the requests?

Comment: No process no alter just forwarding

Comment: There are ready-made solutions for this already, f.e. https://github.com/zounar/php-proxy